# Selecting a textfield and then clicking a button to send text to it in java

Tags: java, netbeans

I have two textfields and 1 button. I want the program to run so that I click the textfield first then click the button, the button sends a text say "1" to the textfield active/ selected. 
Is there a way to achieve this? 
Thank you so much.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is something like onTouchListener(). You may want to visit https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/input/TouchEvent.html

Comment: Please show us a small self-contained bit of code so that we can see what you are working with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do what you are after, so here is just one of them:

You need to add an action listener to each text field and have them set a public variable (Reference to the text field) so that your code knows which text field was the last selected. Then when you click the button you can simply use that variable to know what text field was selected and add a 1 to the end, or do whatever else you want to do, just edit the event.

Example code:

```
//Value to keep track of the last selected text field
public static JTextField lastClicked;
private static javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
private static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
private static javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;

public static void main(String args[])
{
    //Create and display the form
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable()
    {
        public void run()
        {
            //Setup all the components
            jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton("Click Me");
            jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField("One");
            jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField("Two");

            //Add listeners
            jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
            {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt)
                {
                    //Add a 1 to the last selected text field
                    lastClicked.setText(lastClicked.getText() + "1");
                }
            });

            jTextField1.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter()
            {
                public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt)
                {
                    //change the selected text field to this one
                    lastClicked = (JTextField) evt.getSource();
                }
            });

            jTextField2.addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter()
            {
                public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt)
                {
                    //change the selected text field to this one
                    lastClicked = (JTextField) evt.getSource();
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

Beware that in this example we cast the event source to a text field `lastClicked = (JTextField) evt.getSource()`, so this will only work with text fields. If you want to use other components then you should use an integer or an object as the variable type.